# very weird behavior with dragAndDropBy(), dragAndDrop(), moveToElement, etc

Tags: java, selenium, automation, drag-and-drop, webdriver

Not sure if its due to how the application im automating has its UI set up but what Im trying to do is open up a side drawer that holds a couple table rows. I need to drag a table row into another specific area and drop it there to move it.
So heres an Idea of what the interface looks like:

[image: pic]

NOTE: All that whitespace is not a valid area to drop the table row the tablerows are only droppable in a very specific area that becomes visible when the tablerow is right above it.
Im trying to drag the items on the right hand drawer to the left hand side.

When I try to use dragAndDropBy to move to the respective x and y offsets it looks like it doesnt move to the correct location.

I have modified my code now to at least help me see whats wrong and it seems like its not moving to the x coordinate set in my code below:

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);      
        System.out.println(productArrangement.getLocation());
        actions.clickAndHold(productArrangement).moveByOffset(-408, 308).perform();
        System.out.println(productArrangement.getLocation());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
```

As you guys can see all this is trying to do at the moment is see where my element is being moved too and logging if the element is actually moving to the respective direction and it seems like its not being moved at the x coordinate and is moving at the wrong Y coordinate(but at least its moving).

here is my console
[image: coordinates]

I would expect the second coordinate log to have moved to the specified offSets I put in but I have gotten similar behavior for all the methods I've tried so far.
Please advise assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use direct dargAndDrop method like below:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.dragAndDropBy(productArrangement,-408, 308).perform();
```

Comment: its like it isn't moving the element anywhere on the page, the UI behavior is if the item is dropped in an invalid area then the table row returns to its original point. 

I thought this was what was happening at first and that i just had the wrong x and y but it isnt because the code in my post body should have just documented the location of the element and not dropped it anywhere
It was documented to be in an area i did not specify

Comment: Is by any chance , you can get an web element of location you want to drop ? In that case you can use actions.dragAndDropBy(productArrangement,targetelemnt ).perform();

Comment: Please share HTML dom so that I can try in my local .

Comment: actions.dragAndDropBy(productArrangement,targetelemnt ).perform(); ive tried this as well it just does not seem to move the x axis. the elements remain in the drawer Ill send a snippet of the html one second

Comment: Don’t share snippet mate . Please copy HTML it will be easy to work .

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BFhOhGB heres a picture of it, i have no problem locating the table row just getting it to move to the correct coordinates.
Ive been locating the mat-table by its id and traversing down to the mat-row. when i do the thread.sleep using the code in my post body i see the correct element hovering indicating i have it selected.

Comment: sorry i didnt think there was a better way to share it without seeing the way to traverse it